# Ruby on Rails 3 - nested model forms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am using RoR 3 to create a new website for myself.  I have 3 models like so:

```
Ship model has many ShipClasses
Ship model has many ShipEntries
ShipEntry belongs to Ship
ShipEntry belongs to ShipClass
```

When I am creating the Ship I generated nested forms for ShipClasses and ShipEntries.  The problem I have is when creating a `ShipEntry` it should have one of the new `ShipClasses` assigned to it but at the moment when the `Ship` is created I have to go back in and edit the `Ship` and assign the `ShipClasses` to the `ShipEntry` due to the new `ShipClasses` not yet having been created in the DB.  Is it possible at the creation of the ship to assign the newly created `ShipClasses` to the `ShipEntry`?

I hope someone gets what I mean, if you have any trouble understanding this let me know and i'll try to explain further.

Cheers

Eef

Comment: Each `ShipEntry` belongs to only one `ShipClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want to do with active callbacks.

You could use something like `after_create` to link both.

```
after_create :link_ship_entry_and_classes

def link_ship_entry_and_classes
  # whatever you need to do here
end
```

You can read everything there is to know about AC : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea.  this was my exact thought but knowing rails and its wonders I thought it might have had some amazing method to achieve this.  Cheers for responding tho!!